# I need assistance with a join in an SQL query where I am joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table of **enrollment**:

```
+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| enrolleeId   | int(11)     | auto_increment |
| officeId     | int(11)     |                |
| fName        | varchar(45) |                |
| mName        | varchar(45) |                |
| lName        | varchar(45) |                |
| dateOfBirth  | date        |                |
| placeOfBirth | int(11)     |                |
| race         | int(11)     |                |
| role         | varchar(45) |                |
+--------------+-------------+----------------+
```

I have a table of **badge**:

```
+----------------+----------+----------------+
| badgeId        | int(11)  | auto_increment |
| enrolleeId     | int(11)  |                |
| expirationDate | datetime |                |
| badgeImage     | blob     |                |
+----------------+----------+----------------+
```

I have a table of **state**:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| stateId   | int(11)     | 
| code      | varchar(10) | 
| stateName | varchar(45) | 
+-----------+-------------+
```

And I have a table of **race**:

```
+----------+-------------+
| raceId   | int(11)     | 
| code     | varchar(10) | 
| raceName | varchar(45) | 
+----------+-------------+
```

Wen I do a query for the enrollment, this is what is used:

```
SELECT * FROM enrollment e
INNER JOIN state pob on e.placeOfBirth = pob.stateId
INNER JOIN race r on e.race = r.raceId
WHERE e.enrolleeId = 123;
```

This is what I get:

```
'enrolleeId', 'officeId', 'fName', 'mName', 'lName', 'dateOfBirth', 'placeOfBirth', 'race', 'role', 'stateId', 'code', 'stateName', 'raceId', 'code', 'raceName'
'123', '1', 'Joe', 'A', 'Smith', '1970-01-01', '49', '2', 'Software Developer', '49', '49', 'Virginia', '2', '2','Caucasian'
```

Which is absolutely correct.

Now what I want to do is to add in the badge table so that each query for an employee will show their badge number, so I add in another join:

```
SELECT * FROM enrollment e
INNER JOIN state pob on e.placeOfBirth = pob.stateId
INNER JOIN race r on e.race = r.raceId
INNER JOIN badge b on e.enrolleeId = b.enrolleeId
WHERE e.enrolleeId = 123;
```

When I run this query, this is what I get:

```
'enrolleeId', 'officeId', 'fName', 'mName', 'lName', 'dateOfBirth', 'placeOfBirth', 'race', 'role', 'badgeId', 'enrolleeId', 'expirationDate', 'badgeImage'
'123', '1', 'Joe', 'A', 'Smith', '1970-01-01', '49', '2', 'Software Developer', '456', '123', '2019-01-01 13:00:00', '[blob]'
'123', '1', 'Joe', 'A', 'Smith', '1970-01-01', '49', '2', 'Software Developer', '457', '123', '2019-01-01 13:00:00', '[blob]'
'123', '1', 'Joe', 'A', 'Smith', '1970-01-01', '49', '2', 'Software Developer', '458', '123', '2019-01-01 13:00:00', '[blob]'
'123', '1', 'Joe', 'A', 'Smith', '1970-01-01', '49', '2', 'Software Developer', '459', '123', '2019-01-01 13:00:00', '[blob]'
'123', '1', 'Joe', 'A', 'Smith', '1970-01-01', '49', '2', 'Software Developer', '460', '123', '2019-01-01 13:00:00', '[blob]'
'123', '1', 'Joe', 'A', 'Smith', '1970-01-01', '49', '2', 'Software Developer', '461', '123', '2019-01-01 13:00:00', '[blob]'
.
.
.
```

Which is sort of correct. I get the badge information, but I get all the badge IDs for every employee, and I don't get all of the state and race information.

How can I get just the one employee with his badge information?

Thanks!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Can you please check if you have single row in `badge` table for `enrolleeId = 123`?

Comment: @Er_sherlockian `SELECT distinct count(*) FROM badge;` gives me the same as `SELECT count(*) FROM beachdb.badge;`.

Comment: This doesn't matter as badgeId will be distinct in each row. Just tell me the result of `SELECT count(*) FROM badge WHERE enrolleeId = 123;`

Comment: @Er_sherlockian Ok, that's it ... I'm dumb. I **assumed** that the people who created this database wouldn't have created duplicate entries, but they did. My apologies for the uproar.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
INNER JOIN badge b on e.enrolleeId = b.enrolleeId
```

to this:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY enrolleeId ORDER BY anyColumnName) rn 
            FROM badge) b
ON e.enrolleeId = b.enrolleeId and b.rn = 1
```

Comment: A little optimistic that the OP would be using MySQL 8.0+

Comment: @Strawberry Correct ... I am using MySQL version 5.7.21